# Populating a record type using a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to get data from my database but I can't find the error in my code:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is select * from(select d.department_ID, d.department_name,count(d.department_name) cnt from emp e,dept d where e.department_id=d.department_id group by d.department_ID, d.department_name) where cnt>=5;
  TYPE cust_dept IS RECORD(dept_id dept.department_id%type,dept_name dept.department_name%type,emp_name emp.first_name%type);

begin 

FOR i IN c1
loop

    select * into cust_dept  from emp e, dept d where d.department_ID=i.department_ID;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Department_id :'||i.department_id||' '||'department_name :'||i.department_name);--||' '||'customer_name :'||cust_dept.emp_name);
    --FETCH customer_cur into customer_rec;
    --EXIT WHEN customer_cur%notfound;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i.department_id);

 END LOOP;

end;
/
```

The error is:

```
ORA-06550: line 10, column 23:
PLS-00321: expression 'CUST_DEPT' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement
ORA-06550: line 10, column 34:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 10, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare variable of type `cust_dept` and select into it.

Comment: cut_dept is a record for holding data from select into query!

Comment: @Thiyagu - Your `cut_dept` is a type.  It is NOT a variable of record type.  Use `record_var cust_dept;` in `declare` section to declare a variable, and then `select * into record_var`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues on your code

1. cust_dept is a type and not a variable   to declare a variable of
   type cust_dept you need something like this:  `cust_dept_var cust_dept;`
2. Definition of a variable of cust_dept won't solve your
       problem because `select * from emp e, dept d where d.department_ID = i.department_ID` may not return a single answer,
       there may be 2 or more or non result so basically you need to define
       an array variable of cust_dept
3. To result what you need, you can use the code below, you don't need to define a record type or else:


   `begin 

    for x in 

   (select d.department_ID, d.department_name
                     from emp e, dept d
                    where e.department_id = d.department_id
                    group by d.department_ID, d.department_name
                   having count(d.department_name) >= 5) loop



     for y in (select e.department_id, d.department_name
                         from emp e, dept d
                        where d.department_ID = x.department_ID) loop           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Department_id :' || y.department_id || ' ' ||
                                    'department_name :' || y.department_name);
            
    end loop;
      end loop; 
    end;`
4. good luck ;)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can create a code block by clicking on your question and pressing the `{}` button. I notice that your second loop is doing a Cartesian join, which is probably not correct. Also, this could, potentially, all be done in one cursor.